# Maximum contigous subsequence sum of x elements

Tags: sum, max, element, subsequence, contiguous

So I came up with a question that I've looked and searched but with no answer found... What's the best (and by saying the best, I mean the fastest) way to get the **maximum contigous subsequence sum of x elements**?

Imagine that I've: A[] = {2, 4, 1, 10, 40, 50, 22, 1, 24, 12, 40, 11, ...}.
And then I ask:

```
"What is the maximum contigous subsequence on array A with 3 elements?"
```

Please imagine this in a array with more than 100000 elements... Can someone help me?

Thank you for your time and you help!

Answer (score 0):

I Googled it and found [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer-maximum-sum-subarray/):

> Using Divide and Conquer approach, we can find the maximum subarray sum in O(nLogn) time. Following is the Divide and Conquer algorithm.
>
> The Kadane’s Algorithm for this problem takes O(n) time. Therefore the Kadane’s algorithm is better than the Divide and Conquer approach

See [the code](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/):

```
Initialize:
    max_so_far = 0
    max_ending_here = 0

Loop for each element of the array
  (a) max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i]
  (b) if(max_ending_here < 0)
            max_ending_here = 0
  (c) if(max_so_far < max_ending_here)
            max_so_far = max_ending_here
return max_so_far
```

Comment: This is not really what I'm looking, because I need the maximum sum grouped by X elements... Imagine in my example above, the maximum sum is all the elements, since they are all positive, but I want the maximum sum grouped by 3 elements... So: it would be 40 50 22.